# MYSQL count distinct datas depends on if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have really different problem about database query. There is a little bit different scenarios:

I have a table created with 3 columns. They have ID, ItemId, TypeId columns. I need a count query, it should count ItemId and TypeId together but except duplicate columns. For example;

```
Id   ItemId   TypeId
--   ------   ------
1      1        1    -> count +1
2      1        1    -> ignore
3      1        2    -> count -1
4      1        2    -> ignore
5      1        1    -> count +1
```

result count = 1

In the end, if distinct row repeated, count ignore that row. But TypeId data changed for one specific Item it should increase or decrease count. TypeId equals to 1 count +=1, equals to 2 count -=1.

Comment: What would be expected output ? and what is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0 and expected output is 0 or 1. It depends on same Item's type. You may see my expectation in updated post I think

Comment: @SUsta Do check the posted answers.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya they did not work, sorry to no replying

Comment: @SUsta why not working ? Check the DB fiddle demo.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya checked that, but it couldn't solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you would seemingly use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct itemId, typeId)
from t;
```

However, you really have a gaps-and-islands problem.  You are looking at the *ordering* to see where things change.

If I trust that the `id` has no gaps, you can do:

```
select count(*)
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.id = tprev.id + 1
where not ((t.itemId, t.typeid) <=> (tprev.itemId, t.prev.id))
```

Comment: Although this is a good technique to know of in *gaps-and-islands* problem; but I am not really sure that this actually solves OP's weird requirement. OP is basically decrementing count by 1 if typeID = 2.

Comment: Would not replacing `COUNT(*)` with `SUM(IF(t.TypeId = 2, -1, 1))` will work ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya . . . Feel free to offer a solution with your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. This employs [User-defined session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). It will work in all the cases (including gaps in `Id`):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(dt.factor) AS total_count  
FROM 
( SELECT 
    @factor := IF(@item = ItemId AND 
                  @type = TypeId, 
                  0, 
                  IF(TypeID = 2, -1, 1)
                 ) AS factor, 
    @item := ItemId, 
    @type := TypeId 
  FROM your_table 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @item := 0, 
                     @type := 0, 
                     @factor := 0) AS user_init_vars 
  ORDER BY Id
) AS dt
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJedhZmZ51VUHabAP45zYd/0)